# Or gate (||) sorts false as undefined

Tags: javascript, boolean, switch-statement, gate

I have a code like this:

```
var IFS =
    document.isFullScreen || 
    document.webkitIsFullScreen || 
    document.mozIsFullScreen || 
    document.msIsFullScreen;
```

**The exact problem is that the `||` gates sorts `false` as `undefined`, since `isFullScreen` is a boolean.**

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every element is undefined, then IFS will be undefined. Since undefined is a falsy value, you can still make conditional statements as:

```
var IFS =
    document.isFullScreen || 
    document.webkitIsFullScreen || 
    document.mozIsFullScreen || 
    document.msIsFullScreen;

if(!IFS){
    console.log('not full screen');
}
```

If you still want to hold the `false` value in case every other variable is `undefined`, then you can go with something like:

```
var IFS =
    document.isFullScreen || 
    document.webkitIsFullScreen || 
    document.mozIsFullScreen || 
    document.msIsFullScreen || 
    false;
```

Comment: Heh nice, that 2nd code I didn't think about, thanks

Comment: It works the same as !!()

Answer (score -1):

`undefined` is a *falsey* value, meaning the `||` operator will convert will consider it the same as `false`.

If you just want to find the first value which is not defined you could try something like this:

```
var IFS =
    (typeof document.isFullScreen != "undefined") ? document.isFullScreen :
    (typeof document.webkitIsFullScreen != "undefined") ? document.webkitIsFullScreen :
    (typeof document.mozIsFullScreen != "undefined") ? document.mozIsFullScreen :
    (typeof document.msIsFullScreen != "undefined") ? document.msIsFullScreen : 
    false;
```

Or as [*Niet* suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460290/or-gate-sorts-false-as-undefined/22460420#comment34162613_22460420):

```
var IFS =
    ('isFullScreen' in document) ? document.isFullScreen :
    ('webkitIsFullScreen' in document) ? document.webkitIsFullScreen :
    ('mozIsFullScreen' in document) ? document.mozIsFullScreen :
    ('msIsFullScreen' in document) ? document.msIsFullScreen : 
    false;
```

Or you could use an array, like this:

```
var arr = ['isFullScreen', 'webkitIsFullScreen', 'mozIsFullScreen', 'msIsFullScreen'];
var IFS = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] in document) {
        IFS = document[arr[i]];
        break;
    }
}
```

Or like this

```
var arr = ['isFullScreen', 'webkitIsFullScreen', 'mozIsFullScreen', 'msIsFullScreen'];
var key = arr.filter(function(e) { return e in document; })[0];
var IFS = !!document[key];
```

Comment: `'isFullScreen' in document` may be more concise.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Good point, one moment.

Comment: It would be more concise without all that `typeof ... === "undefined"` clutter.

Comment: I'll give it an upvote, excuse me, but who did that downvote?

Comment: You need to negate the result of the `in` operation for it to be equivalent (or almost anyway) to the first example.

Comment: @cookiemonster My first snippet was wrong. I've corrected that now.